# How to use PyTorch to print out the prediction accuracy of every class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to use PyTorch to print out the prediction accuracy of every class based on the official tutorial [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-transfer-learning-tutorial-py)

But things seem to go wrong. My code intends to do this work is as following:

```
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
    for phase in ['train', 'val']:
       ... (this is given by the tutorial)

    (my code)

    class_correct = list(0. for i in range(3))
    class_total = list(0. for i in range(3))

    for data in dataloaders['val']:
        images, labels = data
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        c = (predicted == labels.data).squeeze()

        for i in range(4):
            label = labels.data[i]
            class_correct[label] += c[i]
            class_total[label] += 1

    for i in range(3):
        print('Accuracy of {} : {} / {} = {:.4f} %'.format(i, 
class_correct[i], class_total[i], 100 * class_correct[i].item() / 
class_total[i]))

    print(file = f)
    print()
```

For example, the output of epoch 1/1 is :
[image]

I think the following equation should be satisfied:

> running_corrects := 2 + 2

But things does not happen as I think.

What's wrong there?
Hope someone can point out my fault and teach me how to do this correctly.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem. First, I compared two models' parameters and found out they were the same. So I confirmed that the model is the same. And then, I checked out two inputs and surprisedly found out they were different.

So I reviewed two models' inputs carefully and the answer was that the arguments passed to the second model did **not** update.

Code:

```
for data in dataloaders['val']:
    images, labels = data
    outputs = model(inputs)
```

Change to:

```
for data in dataloaders['val']:
    inputs, labels = data
    outputs = model(inputs)
```

Done!